# Increasing the length of a tuple in Erlang

Tags: erlang, tuples

How can I increase the length of a tuple in Erlang?  For example, suppose `Tup={1,2,3}`, and now I want to add another element to it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In erlang all data, including tuples, is immutable so you cannot change a tuple in any way. "Modifying" a tuple means making a new one with the changes you want, the old one is still there unchanged.

Comment: Why you changed your mind after a month? My answer turned out to be incorrect? Looks like poorly planned reputation manipulation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tuple is not suppose to be a flexible data structure. If you are resizing it often, then you should consider using other [erlang data structures](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html) like [lists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id63758), [maps](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id61978) or [sets](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sets.html) - depends on your expectation. Here is [nice introduction to key-value stores](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#key-value-stores).

But if you really have to extend that tuple, then you can use [erlang:append_element/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#append_element-2):

```
{1,2,3,4} = erlang:append_element({1,2,3}, 4).
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuples aren't mutable so you can't, strictly speaking, increase the length.

Generally, if you want a variable-number-of-things datatype, a tuple will be very inconvenient. For example, iterating over all elements of a list is highly idiomatic, while iterating over all elements of a tuple whose size is unknown at compile-time is a pain.

However, a common pattern is to get a tuple as a result from some function and return elements of that tuple plus additions.

```
country_coords(Name) ->
    {Lat, Lng} = find_address(Name),
    {_Street, _City, _Zip, Country} = geocode(Lat, Lng),
    {ok, Lat, Lng, Country}.
```

Answer (score 2):

erlang:append_element(tuple_whose_length_to_increase, element_to_be).This is the inbuilt function but tuples,lists are not meant to be flexible.So avoid using this function unless there is no other way